# How to create a tile from a TIFF stored in PostGIS using Mapnik in nodejs

Tags: postgis, raster, mapnik, node-js

I stored TIFF in the database using:

```
raster2pgsql -c -C -s 4326 -f geom_raster -F -I evapo_01_201.tif -t 200x200 public.rasters | psql -U postgres -d gaaf -h localhost -p 5432
```

I think it's alright because I can import the raster into QGIS through a connection with PostGIS and everything works.

So the error must be in the nodejs code:

```
export class MapnikGetTileDatasource implements GetTileDatasource {
  private readonly _proj4: string

  constructor () {
    mapnik.register_default_input_plugins()
    this._proj4 = '+init=epsg:4326'
  }

  async getTile (schema: string, table: string, x: number, y: number, z: number): Promise<Buffer> {
    try {
      const dbConfig = {
        host: env.postGreHost,
        dbname: 'gaaf',
        user: env.postGreUser,
        password: env.postGrePass,
        type: 'postgis',
        geometry_field: 'rast',
        table: `${schema}.${table}`,
        extent: '-61.6333829819999863,-18.0415982405563007,-50.2247189819999846,-7.3471822405563003'
      }

      const map = new mapnik.Map(100, 100, this._proj4)
      const layer = new mapnik.Layer('tile', this._proj4)
      layer.datasource = new mapnik.Datasource(
        dbConfig
      )
      map.add_layer(layer)
      map.extent = [-61.633382981999986, -18.0415982405563, -50.224718981999985, -7.347182240556301]
      const image = new mapnik.Image(map.width, map.height)
      return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        map.render(image, { image_format: 'png' }, (err, im) => {
          if (err) return reject(err)
          resolve(im.encodeSync('png'))
        })
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
}
```